# static readonly Dictionary<> declared anonymously

Tags: c#, collections, properties, dictionary

I have a class with static properties. I want this class to have a static, read only dictionary - and I want to initialize it anonymously. I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
    public static readonly Guid ID1 = new Guid("53ba029b-0850-4f51-a358-648411e30972");
    public static readonly Guid ID2 = new Guid("400a9861-21c3-45fd-bf75-95be8f535c58");

public static readonly Dictionary<Guid, String> IdsAndStrings = new Dictionary<Guid, string>(){
    {ID1, "string"},
    {ID2, "string 2"}
};
```

I'm getting an exception when trying to initialize this. The inner exception even mentions incorrect conversion to datetime!? Not sure what's going on there. Is it impossible to instance a new Dictionary<> like this? Should I be using Get Set instead?

EDIT: Please assume all guids and strings are valid.

Comment: Anonymously? You mean using the [Collection Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx) syntax? Or do you mean with anonymous types?

Comment: How are you passing in the GUIDs?

Comment: I've worded it wrongly then - with the collection initializer syntax I meant, thanks Adam.

Comment: @Oded - just by a variable name? I can verify every key in the dictionary is a valid guid. Thanks.

Comment: @DeeMac Can you post some code so we can replicate the error? What you have provided is not enough to formulate an answer with. We can only guess.

Comment: @DeeMac That posted code works fine, the error is coming in from somewhere else.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - thanks for your help, I'll look elsewhere for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not impossible. Using collection initializers, it would look like this:

```
Dictionary<Guid, string> idsAndStrings = new Dictionary<Guid, string>
{
    { Guid.NewGuid(), "" },
    { Guid.NewGuid(), "" },
};
```

Get/set would expose the item as a writable property, which is semantically different to a readonly field - it will offer different behaviour in some cases.

Comment: Isn't that syntactically identical to what I have? Except haven't you got an extra, unwanted comma in there? Thanks a lot. +1.

Comment: Well, assuming that your [GUID1] et al are valid guids and strings, then yes. So what is the real question? What errors are you getting?

Comment: The real question is obviously regarding why it's not working - based on the assumption my guids and strings are fine. And if I'm barking up the wrong tree and should, in fact, be looking into using get/set instead?

Comment: The error I'm getting is on initializing this property, "The type initializer for IdsAndStrings threw an exception."

Comment: @DeeMac - The syntax in the answer (and your example) is correct. If you are getting an error it is probably elsewhere.

Comment: @DeeMac "Not working" means nothing without context. My sample has guids and stings defined in-line, are you expecting to provide them as parameters? The item is also readonly, so you can only define the dictionary once, but can continue to add/remove from it afterwards.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - when did I say "not working?" I explicitly said in the op I was getting an exception on initializing. I'll look elsewhere for my errors but as far as I've checked all guids and strings are valid.

Comment: @DeeMac lol you said not working in your comment. What's the exception and where is the sample application I can use to debug it myself?

Comment: @DeeMac It isn't clear at all. You aren't even using date times, only date time parsing code would throw that and you haven't provided any! Clear is sample code *that throws the exception* and the exception details in the question as it is from VS or your IDE.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - "I'm getting an exception when trying to initialize this"...."The type initializer for IdsAndStrings threw an exception." I'm not wasting my time being petit about it, if I knew where the other DateTime exception was being threw I'd have provided it.

Comment: The exception details are provided by your IDE, it is a simple case to copy that and the stack trace. It isn't necessarily always simple to create a sample app, granted, but none of this matters towards the fact that your question was not clear on the exception *details*.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing syntax looks correct, so the only part that could have an error are the `Guid` or string constants.

If you are attempting to pass in the Guids as strings, use the appropriate `Guid` [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx) explicitly:

```
{ new Guid("XXX-XXX"), "string" },
{ new Guid("YYY-YYY"), "string" },
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, please see the edit to the OP. All guids are being passed as guids and all strings are fine aswell.